# Javascript/jQuery tree renderer

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I need some help in choosing a "tree renderer" similar to jsTree. Since my requirements might be a little different, I would like to ask you to recommend a (preferably jQuery based) plugin for me.

I am trying to (re) write an organization browser, which shows who reports to who etc. The catch is that my server can only throw back JSON (or whatever format) *one time* to the client. That is, on page load, my HTML would have a JSON map containing about 2000 employees, and jsTree/whatever-solution-you-recommend, would render this as a tree.

By one-time, I mean that the client JS cannot repeatedly / progressively ask the server for more data in an AJAX-y fashion. (This is due to some complexities at the server side).

Do you think jsTree is fit for this? I don't want the entire user experience to become sluggish with a 1500-2000 employee org-chart (2000 is the limit here).

Any pointers would help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try jQuery plugin

Plugins/Treeview/treeview
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview/treeview

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on Chrome. Is this supported / not abandoned?

Comment: we actually use it :) and it works well (at least right now :])